# PostFix hostname

Tags: postfix, hostname, dkim

I'm new to postfix and was wondering what hostname I should specify in my main.cf file.

Is it the VPS hostname? or I can use one of the domains I host in the VPS as hostname?

I'm trying to set up DKIM with postfix. I was able to create the key etc but the only problem I have is that in order to make it work, I need to specify the name of the hostname as one of the domains in my VPS which has the DKIM entry in the registar DNS..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Postfix hostname is the same as the domain you got your SSL key & certificate for. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu's hostname itself and is only used when other servers/clients are connecting to your postfix.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify this statement: "is the same as the domain you got your SSL key & certificate for"?

Comment: Well, if you use SSL/TLS with your Postfix you need a valid certificate. And this certificate should be issued for the hostname of your Postfix, because the hostname of Postfix is presented to connecting clients & servers.

Comment: I don't think I use SSL/TLS certificate. I was able to make DKIM work on my VPS, I generated a private key for the domain I needed.